# Unable to start debug on web server Webserver is not configured properly

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the error as i specifed and when i check out the properties `Web Sites` in `IIS` it is showing as per below is it correct i think some are miising here can any one tell how to resolve this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The settings you've shown look rather wrong. I would suggest using the ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, those settings are far from correct.  You'd want to turn read on as well as change the execute permissions setting to at least be "scripts only" if not "scripts and executables" so that the code can be run on the server.

---

Kane's answer also has some good ideas as the registration tool may cover a few other bases that have to be set in order to debug.  Lastly, is the code on the web server set up as a web application or just a web site?